# GooCanvas (Perl GTK2, Goo::Canvas) : Moving path (line) while bound to one point, adding text-box, and connecting it with other canvas items.

Tags: perl, canvas, gtk

I am new to GooCanvas library. Currently using Perl::Gtk2 and Goo::Canvas module.
By looking at code, from demo examples, I can draw primary canvas items, bind keyboard and mouse events (like drag, focus, move) to them.
Now, I want to manipulate path little bit further. Below is code for path (line):

```
my $objLine = Goo::Canvas::Path->new(
                                                                        $root,
                                                                        "M 20 20 L 80 80",
                                                                        'width' => 10.0,
                                                                        'stroke-color' => 'black',
#                                                                       'fill-color' => 'red',
                                                                        'can-focus' => TRUE                                                                     
                                                                        );
$objLine->{id} = "Line";
$objLine->signal_connect('focus_in_event' => \&on_focus_in);
$objLine->signal_connect('focus_out_event' => \&path_on_focus_out);
$objLine->signal_connect('key_press_event' => \&on_key_press);
$objLine->signal_connect('motion_notify_event', \&on_motion_notify);
$objLine->signal_connect('button_press_event', \&on_button_press);
$objLine->signal_connect('button_release_event', \&on_button_release);
```

There are three things, which I want do:
How do I move, extend line while it is fixed to a particular point.
I want to bound a text box to it. I tried doing that with other items, but when items moves, text box remains at its original position.
Using path(line) to connect other canvas items.

I am not asking for direct code (example might be appreciative), but required logic, and name of goocanvas functions(method/property).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GooCanvasGroup`, make it parent of all your items which are supposed to be moved as a unit and move the group around by setting its position.

---

Quick ripof C example from the devhelp manual – **modifying a line by changing the coords of one end**

```
line = 
goo_canvas_polyline_new_line
                        (yourgroup,
                         100.0, 100.0,
                         300.0, 100.0,
                         "stroke-color", "red",
                         "line-width", 5.0,
                         NULL);
```

to update the position (or even just one end of a 2 dot wire)

```
GooCanvasPoints *points = NULL;
g_object_get (line, "points", &points);
// modify "points" as you need to update its position
// it may be needed to re-set the "points" property via 
g_object_set (line, "points", points);
```

**if you want to move a** `GooCanvasGroup`

```
g_object_set (group, "x", new_x_pos, "y", new_y_pos, NULL);
```

Comment: Can I chat with you(at your convenient time, because, I have seen, you are the only person, who has answered, and actually worked on GooCanvas, with self workaround for problem, you faced some times ago). I have read the documentation of GooCanvas on gtk, gone through demos of Goo::Canvas module. By doing that, I have got some basic, idea, but don't know about other things, which are slightly out of my reach. So, I have 2/3 one line, doubts. If you don't mind, can I go on asking in this comment section, and then deleting them, to update in original post, after your answer.

Comment: If you could first rephrase your question what exact issue you get with your code, this would probably help getting more responses – also note I have no clue how good/bad the perl bindings nor any real world experience using perl. Updated answer with quick & dirty draft example.

Comment: Ok! I will go one by one, now. Where can I see devhelp manual? Even, if it is in C no problem, I have little bit familiarity with C.